# Type hint class attribute depending on __init__ argument value

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

I have the following class:

```py
InputType = Literal[
    "TEXT",
    "IMAGE",
    "VIDEO",
]

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, input_type: InputType) -> None:
        if input_type == "VIDEO":
            self.jobs = VideoClass()
        elif input_type == "IMAGE":
            self.jobs = ImageClass()
        elif input_type == "TEXT":
            self.jobs = TextClass()
```

I want to type hint the class attribute "job" with the corresponding class (VideoClass, ImageClass or TextClass).

Currently, pylance shows "jobs" as being one of the three classes.

I tried to add some @overload on an additional method `_init_job_attribute` but it didn't help.

Comment: I don't think you can, since that would depend on runtime data, so a compile-time checker wouldn't be able to determine what it will be.

Comment: type hinting is for static type hinting: all possible values your variables can take when it is executed. Currently your tool is doing the right thing. Assigining the annotation with type-hint at run time would do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overloads to express your intent: just make the class generic in the job type and overload `__new__` or `__init__` to set that type variable according to the input parameter.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from typing import Generic, TypeVar, Literal, cast, overload

InputType = Literal[
    "TEXT",
    "IMAGE",
    "VIDEO",
]

class TextClass: ...
class ImageClass: ...
class VideoClass: ...

_T = TypeVar('_T', TextClass, ImageClass, VideoClass)


class MyClass(Generic[_T]):
    jobs: _T
    
    @overload
    def __init__(self: MyClass[TextClass], input_type: Literal["TEXT"]) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self: MyClass[ImageClass], input_type: Literal["IMAGE"]) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __init__(self: MyClass[VideoClass], input_type: Literal["VIDEO"]) -> None: ...
    
    def __init__(self, input_type: InputType) -> None:
        if input_type == "VIDEO":
            self.jobs = cast(_T, VideoClass())  # type: ignore[redundant-cast]
        elif input_type == "IMAGE":
            self.jobs = cast(_T, ImageClass())  # type: ignore[redundant-cast]
        elif input_type == "TEXT":
            self.jobs = cast(_T, TextClass())  # type: ignore[redundant-cast]
            
reveal_type(MyClass("VIDEO").jobs)  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.VideoClass"
reveal_type(MyClass("IMAGE").jobs)  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.ImageClass"
reveal_type(MyClass("TEXT").jobs)  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.TextClass"
```

Ignore comments and casts above are used to inform `mypy` that you're sure that class instance you're assigning is indeed exactly of `_T` type and not one of its options. It's necessary, because `mypy` does not take overloads into account while checking function body. Any external caller will be able to instantiate `MyClass` only with three options you allowed (if he's also running some type checker, of course).

Here's a [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=290e4a915bad2a4d59e6120367852cc0).

Answer (score 3):

I would do the following:

1. Make the class generic in the job type
2. Make `__init__` simply take an appropriate job instance, rather than a text string.
3. Define separate class methods that return a concrete instance, rather than a single method that converts a string to a job class.

```
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


T = TypeVar('T', TextClass, VideoClass, ImageClass)


class MyClass(Generic[T])
    jobs: T

    def __init__(self, jobs: T) -> None:
        self.jobs = jobs
                    
    @classmethod
    def text_class(cls) -> MyClass[TextClass]:
        return cls(TextClass())

    @classmethod
    def video_class(cls) -> MyClass[VideoClass]:
        return cls(VideoClass())

    @classmethod
    def image_class(cls) -> MyClass[ImageClass]:
        return cls(ImageClass())
```